# Coordinates of layer inside CCParallaxNode

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone, openid

I use CCParallaxNode from cocos2d framework for automatization scrolling.
First node is CCSprite, but second node is big layer in wich I draw with ES Open GL. 
When user touches I have to change something in second layer subject to coordinates of touch.
I catch touches in parent of CParaxNode, and I get coordinates from 0 to width of screen.
How can I transform this coordinates to layer coordinates?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try this:

```
[myParallaxNode convertTouchToNodeSpace:myTouch];
```

or else:

```
CCNode *insideLayer = [myParallaxNode getChildByTag:kMyLayerTag];
[insideLayer convertTouchToNodeSpace:myTouch];
```

hope it helps..